# Should I populate view model inside or before creating it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm not sure if softwareengineering exchange is right for the question.

I need to populate view model with some values I query from the database.

I do it like:

```
var db = new NPoco.Database(connection);
// Get some values from database
//...
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(db) 
{
 //assign values from database
};

// show view and assign view model
```

I get all POCOs I need and I assign them to my view model before passing it to the view. And I pass database instance to my view model.

And it got me thinking. Should the creator of view model be responsible for populating it, or viewmodel could populate it in the constructor?

Am I doing it right currently?

Comment: Can ViewModel exist without this data? Would it make sense to create this ViewModel with the data being set to "default"?

Comment: I don't know. I think not.

Comment: I need the data.

Comment: Your ViewModel can pull the data from the `db` instance.  That's kind of the whole point of a View Model: to coordination communication between the View and the Model.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what if I have some ids that are only known outside view model and I want to fetch those ids.

Comment: You can either pass those IDs into the ViewModel and load your data from the db there, or load the data outside of the ViewModel and pass that data in.  I know that probably sounds obvious, but those are your choices.

Comment: so it doesn't really matter if I do it in ViewModel, or outside of it?

Comment: Ask yourself if the data is specific to that particular ViewModel.  If it is, pull it in the ViewModel.  If it's not (i.e. that specific data set is used in multiple places), put a method in the Model to retrieve it and call that method from your ViewModel.

Comment: I think I use this viewmodel only once with specific view. I think I will stay with the current method i.e. assigning properties outside.